# Role base authentication with custom error with role name in dot net 6

Tags: asp.net, .net, authentication, .net-core, .net-6.0

I use the below the line for role based authentication at top of methods in controllers

```
[HttpGet("getAll"), Authorize(Roles = "GetAll")]
```

When a user doesn't have access to this role, I want to tell the user that you need the role "GetAll"

Is it possible?

Comment: I use a workaround without the Authorize(Role = role) attribute, only Authorize for log in. Basically I check in the controller itself if the user is in that role and if not I return Unauthorized(new { message = "You are not in that role" }) and display the error with a javascript notification.

Comment: Also think about whether you really want to add that information to you response. The more information you give back to the user regarding the authentication/authorization process the more surface you give to a potential attacker to exploit your system.

Comment: @404 I give the role name when the user has authenticated and just doesn't have the specific role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the role in the method, something like this:

```
[HttpGet("getAll"), Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll()
        {
            if (!Roles.Any(r => r == "getAll"))
            {
                return Unauthorized("Pass the role name");
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

**Roles** contains the roles that user access

Comment: do we have to add this check to every action?

Comment: @ArhamAnees yes

Comment: Figured out action filter approach, you can checkout at  https://github.com/arham-anees/CleanArchitectureNetCore/blob/main/CleanArhitectureNetCore.WebApi/ActionFilters/Authorize.cs

Answer (score 0):

I know I am very late but it may help someone in future.
I have added an action filter and uses it on actions/controllers. I have added it to my template too, https://github.com/arham-anees/CleanArchitectureNetCore/blob/main/CleanArhitectureNetCore.WebApi/ActionFilters/Authorize.cs

First of all create an attribute class `public class AuthorizeAttribute:Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter`. You can name anything instead of `AuthorizeAttribute` then use as attribute above actions/controllers without `Attribute` part.

The action will be called anytime action is called and will perform action and perform your actions. For role based Authenticated, I have kept my controllers clean with attributes while authenticating user on basis of role. you can see it here https://github.com/arham-anees/CleanArchitectureNetCore/blob/main/CleanArhitectureNetCore.WebApi/Controllers/ValuesController.cs#L18